# How To Disable/Bypass Content-Security-Policy with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, greasemonkey, content-security-policy, tampermonkey

So i used firebase auth to connect to small web app i made in tampermonkey

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

The issue is when i use it on the target page the content get blocked because
`Content-Security-Policy` but this can be fixed in Firefox by disabling *Content-Security-Policy*

**What i tried**

1 / Fetch the data with this script
`fetch(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))`
https://github.com/mitchellmebane/GM_fetch/blob/master/GM_fetch.js

2/ **GM.xmlHttpRequest**

```
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "...googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key="bla..bla",
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
   data: {"email":email,"password":password,"returnSecureToken":true},

 onload: function(response) {
   auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  }
})
```

3 / Chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

[GM.xmlHttpRequest](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest) worked for me. Example:

```
// @grant    GM.xmlHttpRequest

const response = await GM.xmlHttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://example-website.com/api/people,
});
```